# What can I use to cover cosmetic chips in my crash helmet?

Tags: motorcycle, repair, crash-helmet

I have some small cosmetic chips in my motorcycle crash helmet. Chips look something like this:

[image: chips on motorbike helmet]

I am thinking of covering them up for both cosmetic reasons and to keep the helmet as waterproof as possible. What can I use to do this?  I was thinking about applying a thin layer of epoxy resin. Would that work?

Comment: Are they cosmetic or are they holes in the outer layer?   What about some clear nail polish ?

Comment: @Criggie Let's say both.

Comment: Safety concerns aside, epoxy will work, but will be messy. (You'll wind up with smears and, most likely, extra epoxy around the repair that will have to be sanded or otherwise removed, which presents the opportunity to further damage the surface.) Have you considered Bondo? It's easier to clean up than epoxy and holds paint quite well.

Comment: you are worried about the chips... I'm more worried about how off center and crooked the "vents" or whatever those things are that are stuck onto the top of the helmet are.

Comment: @DavidLively What is bondo? Does it exist on this side of the Pond? :)

Comment: It's a polyester-based filler compound (putty) used to (cheaply) repair dents, make molds, etc. There are other brands available in the UK. Google suggests http://www.milliput.com/. Basically, you mix it up, fill in your holes / dents / whatever, let it set, sand it, prime and paint. You could also just use some touch-up paint or spray paint for the scratches. It all depends on how much time / effort you want to invest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue with helmet cosmetic damage surrounds having a paint that is compatible with polymers that are being used to construct the shell.  I have researched what they are and have been unable to find out what the various manufacturers use as they are probably trade secrets and publishing their intellectual property regarding their fancy polymer shell.

I decided, rather than really make this a project, to find helmet paint that matched.  Since my helmet was matte black, that was easy.

I did the following:

- Rubbed out as much of the damage I could with 1000 grit rubbing compound.
- Cleaned the surface with lacquer thinner to get any oil and contaminates off the surface.
- Gave it a light coat of matte black *on the area* of scratches and called it done.

I basically had the exact same issue with my SHOEI that I decided to wear while I tumbled through a gravel trap a couple of years ago.  I don't have any good pictures of what it did look like but here's a pic I just snapped.

[**Here is where I procured my matte paint**](http://www.colorrite.com/department/schuberth-helmet-paint-11586.cfm), this is not a product endorsement.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule of thumb, helmets should be replaced after 5 years of use. Sooner if the outer shell is damaged (cracked or punctured).

There are many different opinions about dealing with helmet surfaces. It seems the main concern is in avoiding products that contain chemicals that will damage the outer shell materials. If you do choose an epoxy, just make sure it is compatible with your helmet.

As an alternative, decals (stickers) can also be a solution to cover blemishes.

[Snell](http://www.smf.org/helmetfaq) has some great info on their site that may help you.

Comment: Don't think the decals will help with the waterproofness issue, whether that is an issue or not.

Comment: If your helmet leaks due to surface damage, I'd suggest replacing it. I suggested decal as an alternative because some plastic decals are waterproof. Of course I am speculating because I have no idea what the actual condition of your helmet is, what decals are available to you, nor what conditions you use you ride in.

Comment: if the surface is damaged enough to leak, the outer shell is cracked right through and needs replacement. the shell material is painted for looks,. not waterproofness